# Subordination of a Levy process when the "subordinator" is not nondecreasing

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

If $X_t$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued Levy process and $Z_t$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued subordinator, we know that $X_{Z_t}$ is also Levy process. My question is, are there processes $Z_t$ which are not non-decreasing, for which $X_{Z_t}$ is a Levy process? In addition to this, which part of the definition of a Levy process fails if the non-decreasing assumption is not satisfied?

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am very new to Levy processes.

Comment: Do you mean on the non-negative half line? If so, what about $|X_{|Z_t|}|$ where again, $X_t,Z_t$ are independent Brownian motions? Further, other than having some intuitive appeal, I don't see why the index must be non-decreasing. For example, standard Brownian motion is time reversible.

Comment: @ John : There might be a little confusion as Subordinators are Lévy processes that are required to be non decreasing (almost surely).Moreover to apply the time change it is necessary that the subordinator be positive at 0 for the process $X_Z$ to  be defined. Best regards

Comment: I understand that Subordinator are Levy process that are both non-negative and non-decreasing. My question is; if we construct a process $X_Z$ in a fashion analogous to subordination, is the resulting process a Levy process if both $X$ and $Z$ are. If not, which part of the definition of a Levy process fails?

Comment: In addition, are there particular examples where $X_Z$ is a Levy process when $Z$ is not a subordinator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, Lévy processes $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ are considered, i.e. the time $t$ is non-negative. This means that we need the subordinator $(Z_t)_{t \geq 0}$ to satisfy $Z_t \geq 0$. Since Lévy processes have very nice properties, the non-negativity already implies the monotonicity.

The deeper reason why we need the monotonicity lies somewhere else: The monotonicity of $(Z_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is necessary in order to ensure that $(X_{Z_t})_{t \geq 0}$ has independent increments. This becomes more obvious, if we consider a deterministic subordination, i.e. $f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ and the corresponding "subordinated" process $Y_t := X_{f(t)}$. If $f$ is not increasing, then $Y_t$ has in general no independent increments. (E.g. choose

$$f(t) := \begin{cases} t & t < 1 \\ 2-t & t \in [1,2] \\ 0 & t>2 \end{cases},$$

then $Y_1-Y_0$ is not independent from $Y_{2}-Y_1$.) Obviously, $f$ is not a Lévy process; nevertheless, this shows that something with the independence goes wrong if the subordinator is not increasing.

Comment: Suppose $X_t,Z_t$ are independent Brownian motions. Then, what can we say about $X_{Z_t}$?

Comment: @John Sorry, I have rewritten my answer. I was too hasty in claiming that all works fine if we glue two processes together.

Comment: Thank's Saz. It makes sense now.