# Is the subordination of white noise also white noise?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

Say $S$ is a subordinator (an almost surely increasing Levy Process). My understanding from sources like [Subordination of a Levy process when the "subordinator" is not nondecreasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959121/subordination-of-a-levy-process-when-the-subordinator-is-not-nondecreasing) is that for any Levy process, such as the wiener process $W$, $W(S(t))$ is also a Levy process.

Now say $X$ is white noise. Is the stochastic process $X(S(t))$ also white noise? What about the process $X(X(t))$? Does this change if $X$ is non-stationary?